# How to redirect back from View controller to Main Story board in IOS app

Tags: ios, redirect, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I've one query regarding redirect from View controller to main story board In my IOS app. In My application login  screen is Main Storyboard  and register screen is view controller. I know code of redirect from Main Story board (Login) to view controller (register) but i don't know how to redirect back from View controller (Register) to Main storyboard (Login).

Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks 
Shailesh

Comment: How are you going from Login to register? How you go back depends on how you go forward.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Please check out below code that i use to redirect from login(main storyboard) screen to register (view controller) screen.

UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    
    Register *mvc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Register"];
    
    mvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    
    [self presentViewController:mvc animated:YES completion:NULL];

Thanks1

Comment: In mvc just put [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: I've one more question How can i redirect from One view controller to another view controller. Is it same as Main story board to another view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just write one line code

```
-(IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

}
```

Comment: I've one more question How can i redirect from One view controller to another view controller. Is it same as Main story board to another view controller?

Comment: You can redirect from one view controller to another view controller by using UINavigationController or Modal.

Comment: Hi Kalpesh, Thanks for your quick reply. I am new in IOS so, i've not much knowledge of syntax etc... I appreciate if you write code here... I want to redirect from Register (View Controller) to Forgot Password (View Controller). Thanks

Comment: Before you start coding . Read this tutorial carefully  http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1.